# How to I delay inside a for loop in Swift 3?

Tags: for-loop, swift3, delay

The Swift 3 convention of the Delay:

```
func delay(_ delay: Double, closure: @escaping ()->()){
    let when = DispatchTime.now() + delay
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: closure)
}
```

Where I call it :

```
delay(1.0, closure: { 
                        //Enter Code
                    })
```

This works asynchrony so If i put this inside of for loop, then it will execute all these commands at once after delay.

I am in a for loop like so:

```
for i in array{
    //I want to do a delay here
         for j in i{
        //I also want to do a delay here
      }
    }
```

The point of this is I want there to be a delay inside the first for loop before it goes to the "j" for loop, then inside the "j" for loop, I want a delay before it goes to the next J.

Please Help, because this delay function in Swift 3 is asynchronous.

Comment: Use `Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1.0)` instead of `asyncAfter `

Answer (score 0):

In below, snippet, your each process will happen after some time interval for processing i and j. All process will happen in async, so no issue will occur.

```
for var i:Int in 10..<20 {
 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 1, execute: {
    for var j:Int in 10..<20 {
       DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 2, execute: {
       })
       j += 1
    }
 })
 i += 1
}
```

Another way of representing this for loop is using `stride`

```
public func logger(logMessage: Any) {
    print("\(Date()) \(logMessage)")
}

for var i in stride(from: 10, through: 20, by: 1) {

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 1, execute: {
        logger(logMessage: "i:\(i)")
        for var j in stride(from: 30, through: 40, by: 1){
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 2, execute: {
                logger(logMessage: "j:\(j)")
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: This does not work, prints out 10 - 20 all at the same time, this is now what I needed, I need it to print 10, iterate through and print 10 - 20 at different times, then go to 11 and do the same thing

Comment: come on http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127579/swift chat, we can discuss there